# How to change the value of the version value in the POM file when tag in gitlab

Tags: maven, gitlab, tags

the pom file like this:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.ctran</groupId>
<artifactId>north-resource-sync</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>north-resource-sync</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

the version value change as test-SNAPSHOT when using New Tag in gitlab, i want the version change as test-SNAPSHOT int the pom file , not 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, how could i do?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use maven-release-plugin which will do all the necessary things...(Apart from using a old version of spring boot https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support)

Comment: now,This operation is to manually tag gitlab, and then use the value of tag to change the value of version in the jar package，Finally, push the jar package to nexus. hou could i do? thank.

Comment: As I mentioned use the maven-release-plugin that will do the needed steps...

Comment: As alternative for maven-release-plugin the versions-maven-plugin could be useful (https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two common solutions for changing versions in Maven-POMs via Maven-plugins e.g. to `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.

**[Maven-Release-Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html)**

```
mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The Maven-Goal `release:update-versions` performs only the versions update without making other modifications. The parameter `--batch-mode` activates the batch-mode which automatically use default values instead of asking you via prompt for those values. Therefore the version must be set as a user property `-DdevelopmentVersion`.

**[Versions-Maven-Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html)**

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT versions:commit
```

The Maven-Goal `versions:set` performs versions update to the version set via `-DnewVersion` and creates a backup of the POM. The subsequent Maven-goal `versions:commit` removes the backup of the POM. The creation of the backup POM can be suppressed with the user property `-DgenerateBackupPoms=false`.