# How to fully automate deployment of multiple Maven projects in specific order in Gitlab?

Tags: maven, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

I have a complex Maven project structure that has many defined dependencies in it. Also dependencies used in the project are not just external but also internal and I am working on them. All of them are repositories stored on Gitlab. There is defined dependency graph that looks like a tree.

### Example

Here is a simple example of how dependencies are defined:

```
          /--> C
A ---> B -        /--> D
          \--> D -
                  \--> E
```

In this example it can be seen that Maven project `A` has dependency on project `B`. Also project `B` has included dependencies `C` and `D` inside it. Project `D` includes dependencies on projects `D` and `E`.

We can now split this tree in layers numbered from 0 to 3:

```
  3 |   2   |    1   |   0  
____________________________
    |       | /--> C |
  A |---> B |-       | /--> D
    |       | \--> D |-
    |       |        | \--> E
```

After every commit/merge into `develop` branch for all projects, pipeline for build and deployment will automatically run.

The tree is much more complex, but for example this is enough good.

### PROBLEM

If I commit some changes into project `E`, I have to merge my feature branch into `develop` branch so the automatic build and deployment of JAR file will be done, but now the boring part starts... I have to do the same for every Maven project starting from `E` to the left side in above graph and the only change there is the new version of the `E` project in their POM files. I also have to deploy new SNAPSHOT versions for all projects from right layers to left, but also in every layer I have to deploy projects from top to bottom. For example, I will have to first deploy project `C` and then `D` inside layer number 1.

Deployment order would look like this:

```
E, C, D, B, and then finally A.
```

### What I want to achieve?

After I commit my changes into project `E`, I would like that in the order defined above all the projects starting from `E` to the left side:

- Use new version of the project `E` in their POM files
- Change their version to one higher
- Run the build and deploy script

### What I do now?

Currently I am using a single runner (to be sure that I will deploy only one repository at the time) for all projects above and I am doing this manually. I am manually replacing new version of the project in all POM files in all projects and doing it in the order described above. I am also waiting for pipeline to finish and when I see that it is done, I am doing then manually same thing for next project, until I don't finish the project `A`.

Is there any way to automate this? I need some solution for automatic SNAPSHOT version update for example, then some autimated way of deploying all the projects from right to left (maybe to use multi-project pipelines?).

Comment: Nice question! We had the same problems and solved them with using a combination of multi-project-pipelines, child-pipelines and maven-versions-plugin. I will soon answer your question with our approach.

Comment: Thank you @JakobLiskow, I already thought about Gitlab Multi-project pipelines. I just thought that there is some other better tool for automating all these that people are using in IT sectors. I am excited about your comment :)

Comment: @JakobLiskow, can you please give me some useful links that I could use to help me find a solution before you don't answer my question? That would help me a lot.

Comment: Sorry for not answering yet. I'm busy at the moment. Useful links: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines https://stackoverflow.com/a/72865207/3535187 https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269921/3535187 https://jsonnet.org/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/51514850/3535187